# openresty nginx conf to capture location starting with a specific value

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, openresty

I am using openresty and in my default.conf, I am checking for certain APIs that if the request is for this API, then I need to send the request to a backend as is. I am doing it like this:

```
location = /y/products/ {
  include /xxx/yyy/some.conf;
}
```

This works fine. However, I want to be able to do something similar for an API call that starts with /y/products

so, lets say my API could be to something like:

```
y/products/00000001-2aef-13ef-b12f-8b7e4f3f4e1a/check?val=abcdefgh
```

How do I change the location check syntax above to capture requests of this form, so I can decide what to do for those API calls?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equal sign:

```
location /y/products/ {
  ...
}
```

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression.

> Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location